# monitor progress in a Monte Carlo algorithm

Tags: montecarlo

I am making a Monte Carlo algorithm and I want to display its progress in a progress bar (values from 0% to 100%)

My initial thought is to compare the standard deviation generated by the algorithm with the solution tolerance specified.

like

> progress = 100 * specified_tolerance / standard_deviation

However I wonder if there is something better, or if my approach has some pitfall.

[EDIT]
A sample picture of the simulations I'm making:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, problem, I think, with your solution is that std.dev is going down as inverse square root of `N` (number of events generated), and assuming that `N` is proportional to simulation time, your scale would behave like

```
progress = C * sqrt(t)
```

which is quite unnatural if you ask me

I would redo scale to be linear, which means dealing with squared sigma (or variance)

UPDATE

thinking about it, I would do both. Typically you have green/blue bar and some numbers displaying % on top of that. I would separate the two indicators, and
make progress bar linear (dealing with variance), but percent display dealing with std.dev and therefore, being sqrt(). It would look a bit weird, but might be the best of two worlds

Comment: Indeed the variance would be better. What does `C` and `t` mean in you progress expression?

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera t is time, C is some constant

Comment: I believe that if my progress is directly linked to the execution time I won be able to set the progress bar maximum value in advance since I don know how long will it take to complete the simulation. Instead I need a measurement of the variability of the average that can be normalized in [0, 1] for example.